# функция должна возвращать результат или сообщить, что не может вычислит. Как сделать красиво и правильно?

Tags: python, чистый-код, реализация

я новичек в питоне, но подобный вопрос возникал раньше с другими языкам, и я не нашел пока подходящего мне решения.

вопрос не конкретный - интересует общий подход к реализации:

Некая функция вычисляет нечто, и есть два результата вычисления -

1. Вычисление выполнено - вернуть результат.
2. Результат вычисления не подходит - тогда результат не интересен, но нужно передать сообщение выше по иерархии вызовов.

Я придумал пока только три варианта реализации- ни один мне не нравится:

1. в случае неудачи вернуть False или None и уже при вызове функции разобраться с выдачей сообщения.

   ```
    def MyFunction():
        # ...
        result = someCalculation()
        # ...
        if result == SOMTHING_UNFIT:
            return False
        else:
            return result
    # ...
    result = MyFunction()
    if result == False:
        print 'Вычисление закончено. Результат не получен.'
    else:
        DoSomething(result)
   ```
2. в случае неудачи выбросить исключение и поймать его, там где нужно

   ```
    def MyFunction():
        # ...
        result = someCalculation()
        # ...
        if result == SOMTHING_UNFIT:
            raise MyException('Вычисление закончено. Результат не получен.')
        else:
            return result
    # ...
    try:
        result = MyFunction()
    except MyException as e:
        print(e.args)

    DoSomething(result)
   ```
3. Вернуть словарь, с несолькоми полями

   ```
    def MyFunction():
        # ...
        result = someCalculation()
        # ...
        if result == SOMTHING_UNFIT:
            return {
                'fit': False,
                'message': 'Вычисление закончено. Результат не получен.',
                'result': None,
            }
        else:
            return {
                'fit': True,
                'message': None,
                'result': result,
            }
    # ...
    result_dict = MyFunction()

    if result_dict['fit'] == False
        print(result_dict['message'])
    else:
        DoSomething(result_dict['result'])
   ```

Чем мне не нравятся эти решения:

1. возвращаемое значени используется в двух целях - как выдача результата и как индикатор успешности выполнения вычисления. мне кажется, что это неправильно.
2. выдается куча сообщений, но на самом деле это не исключения, или ошибки - это штатный вариант иногда результат можно вычислить, а иногда нет...
3. сильно громоздко, и одни поля не используются в одном случае, а другие в другом

Вопросы:

1. Оптимальный вариант реализации, как это обычно делается (шаблон проектирования?)
2. есть ли какой-нибудь механизм передать сообщение наверх напрямую (сквозь цепочки вызовов функций, циклы) - типа исключения, но без сообшений об ошибках... вроде какой-нибудь GOTO, аспект, декоратор, DI контейнер, mixin? магия?

Comment: А что должно происходить с той цепочкой вызовов, если значение внутри не получено ? они должны продолжить работу дальше ? Если да, то точно не исключение. А если они должны работу прервать на этом месте то исключение как раз для этого и предназначено

Comment: Четвёртый вариант: возвращать пустой список `[]` в случае ошибки и список со значением `[<result>]` в случае успеха. Это почти тоже самое что `Optional` в других языках программирования. Кстати, можно сделать `Optional` - пишется он не сложно и хорошо документирует что возвращает функция.

Comment: В завиисимости от вида возвращаемого значения можно завести `NullResult` (Null Object). В некоторых задачах он сильно упрощает использование вашей функции. Но это не универсальный рецепт, под каждую функцию (и контекст вызова) надо будет придумывать свой `NullResult`. И не всегда получится хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему вариант с возвратом `None` самый нормальный если вы считаете, что это не исключительная ситуация. Если это исключительная ситуация - тогда надо выбрасывать исключение (`Exception`).

Значение `None` - необычное значение, которое не должно возвращаться в нормальном случае.
Кроме того, возвращаемое значение легко проверить на `None`:

```
res = func(...)

if res is None:
    ...
```

В зависимости от необходимого поведения, можно добавить `logging` и печатать предупреждения (`warning`).

Comment: Только что, своим примером, вы ввели `None` в круг "нормальных" возвращаемых значений.

Answer (score 2):

Традиционно, для решения проблемы с возвратом при ошибке, в Python используется простой приём: функция возвращает 2 значения - результат своей работы и признак наличия ошибки. Как то так:

```
if .... :
    # Всё хорошо
    return result, False
else:
    return None, True
```

А в вызывающей программе пишите:

```
(x, error) = MyFunction(...)
if error:
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле все варианты вполне нормальные. Про нюансы других вариантов написали уже в других ответах, а я хочу сказать про исключения. Вас ведь никто не заставляет печатать пойманное исключение `MyException`. Вы можете просто пробрасывать именно это исключение насколько вам нужно наверх, и только где-то наверху что-то вывести, да и то, если вам это нужно. Это просто механизм возврата управления выше по цепочке, если возникла такая необходимость.